# Specifying index with Symfony2 for Doctrine's PersistentCollection

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Can anybody tell me how I can configure Symfony2/Doctrine to index objects within a PersistentCollection, from a specified column in the entity?

For example assume we have two tables; categories and products, with many products to one category. When I use the repository to load a category, and then call `getProducts()` to load the products, I want them to be returned indexed by the product ID, or whatever column I specify. Currently they're just indexed incrementally from zero.

Is there anyway to do this, or do I need to loop through and manually set the keys myself?

Answer (score 1):

Mapping `OneToMany` associations allows you to define an `indexBy` property. With [annotation mappings](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html), it would look like following

```
class Category
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Products", indexBy="productId", mappedBy="product")
     */
    protected $products;

    // ...
}
```

[XML](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/xml-mapping.html), [YAML](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/yaml-mapping.html) and [PHP mappings](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/php-mapping.html) allow this too, and this works also with `ManyToMany`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `mappedBy`?

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie ah yes, that property is missing here :) But `indexedBy` is what the question was about